# Long file path in VSCode peek definition window

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I use the peek definition in VSCode, and the title of the peek window is a long file path I cannot see the filename. Is there any setting we can change so that we can show the filename/the end of the file path?

[image: VSCode screenshot]

Comment: I don't seem to have that extension installed (something related to SASS, maybe?) so this is a blind shot but, are you opening standalone files or the entire project folder?

Comment: It's a project folder. And it's not just sass, I use peek definition with another language too and it has the same behavior.

Comment: My bad. That seems to be feature behaviour, it also displays full paths in my computer. I'm afraid I don't have any suggestion.

Comment: It's ok to display the full path, but it just needs to show the end of it. Showing the start of the file path is not useful.